# is Hizashi a noun or a proper name?

Tags: words, nouns

I am considering using this word to name a new brand however I don't want it to be named after the popular Anime character. Does Hizashi mean "rays of the sun" and can it be separated from the character?

Answer (score 4):

> Is Hizashi a noun or a proper name?

Yes.  :)

In more detail, *hizashi* is both.

#### As a name

As we can see [here in Jim Breen's mirror of the ENAMDICT name dictionary](http://nihongo.monash.edu/cgi-bin/wwwjdic?2MUJ%E3%81%B2%E3%81%96%E3%81%97), ひざし as a name may have the following spellings and name types:

- 陽 -- feminine given name, as indicated by the `(f)` marker after the "Hizashi" reading.
- 日差子 -- given name, of uncertain gender, as indicated by the `(g)` marker -- but given the 子 in the spelling, this is almost certainly a feminine name.
- 陽向 -- surname, as indicated by the `(s)` marker.

#### As a noun

And as we can see [here in Jim Breen's mirror of the EDICT general terms dictionary](http://nihongo.monash.edu/cgi-bin/wwwjdic?1MUJ%E3%81%B2%E3%81%96%E3%81%97), ひざし as a noun may have the following spellings, all with the same sense of "sunlight; rays of the sun":

- 日差し
- 陽射し
- 日射し
- 陽差し
- 日ざし
- 陽ざし
- 日差
- 陽射

#### Derivation

The term, as either name or noun, derives from [日]{hi} ("sun") + [差し]{sashi} ("sticking or pointing through", here in reference to the beams of sunlight).

Comment: Thank you very much! Very helpful.